# Neo4j - JPA for server database

Tags: java, jpa, neo4j, persistence

I have a **server** Neo4j database. I'd like to connect it with my Java application using JPA. There are few possibilities, for example:

- Hibernate OGM
- DataNucleus

However, every Neo4j JPA implementation I found works only with **embedded** databases.

Currently I managed to solve this temporary by using direct queries to [Neo4J REST interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386013/how-to-connect-to-a-locally-installed-neo4j-server-using-java).

Are there any other options for using server Neo4j database in my application?

Comment: There is a new, plain java, OGM worked on for Neo4j server, stay tuned for the next weeks. We'll announce the first milestone.

Comment: @Michael That's a great news, Michael!

Comment: It needs to be noted that "Neo4j OGM" is NOT a Neo4j JPA provider. It is yet another API (with yet another set of annotations), so does not answer the question posed here. Maybe the reason why those JPA providers haven't got support for a server Neo4J is that there doesn't seem to be a way of getting a GraphDatabaseService for a Neo4j server ... or is there???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest Hibernate OGM, comes now with Remote Neo4j server support:
http://hibernate.org/ogm/